# MongoDb: Is it harmful to issue a command to enable sharding on a collection which already has sharding enabled?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

One of our project is using MongoDb and our database => collections are sharded. BTW, our collection gets created dynamically and hence we had to write a code inside our Application layer written in PHP to inform MongoDb to shard the collections. Hence I am looking for two options:

1. Is there any way to identify if the collection is shareded via PHP? [or]
2. Is there any problem in telling MongoDb to shard a collection which is sharded?

Comment: do you mean "is it harmful to issue a command to enable sharding on a collection which already has sharding enabled"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1] you can identify whether the collection is sharded or not by manipulating string output given by `db.printShardingStatus()`
check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13027269/1424605) to know how to print output of MongoDB

2] No issue to ask MongoDB to shard a collection which is already sharded.
Mongo wil never set "ok" to 1 if it is already sharded.
`db.runCommand({ enablesharding : "sharded_db_name" })

{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "already enabled" }`

Answer (score 0):

1.I'm not entirely sure on this as I don't use the PHP driver, however, on the shell when one runs `sh.status()`, it is possible to see what the sharded collection is. For example, below I have sharded the "tweets" collection in the "twitter" database -

```
 databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "twitter",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
        twitter.tweets chunks:
                shard0001   11
                shard0002   11
                shard0000   12
```

There's further sharding documentation [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/sharding/).

PHP driver documentation is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php).

2.You can't shard a sharded collection, not really sure why you need to....it doesn't make sense.

Comment: like I said, my collections are created dynamically and I want to shard those collections since they are created from Application Layer (not in a traditional way), having said that, I don't want to monitor whether my collection new and shoot a command to enable sharding.